# vscode always opens welcome screen on startup instead of last opened folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I built my own custom version of vscode to add some features to the minimap, namely highlighting when highlighting a word. All is well and good, apart from the issue where my version of vscode never remembers the last opened folder and always opens the welcome screen instead.

The official version of vscode does not do this and opens the last opened folder, as expected. What is wrong with my version?

For reference, this is the code I used to build my version of vscode: https://github.com/abhijitvalluri/vscode/tree/minimap_enhancements

Answer (score 35):

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings you need to set workbench.startupEditor to "None".

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, you can go to **File > Preferences > Settings**, search **"Startup Editor"** in **"Search Settings"** and choose **"None"** from the drop-down menu.

Comment: On the left sidebar, it is under the Workbench menu. Scrolldown to "Startup editor".

Comment: I set it to "none" and the welcome page still appears

Answer (score 5):

## First option (Simpler)

You can deselect this option on the screen itself:

[image: VSCode]

At the bottom of the page you have the following option:

[image: VSCode]

## Second option (More complex)

Go to:

```
File > Preferences > Settings > Workbench > Startup Editor
```

E Selecione a opção "None":

[image: VSCode]

Comment: On the latest ESP-IDF plugin, the "show welcome screen..." checkbox is now in the upper left corner. :) That option worked for me. When I tried setting startup editor to "none" it had no effect.